# Saving specific value Javascript

Tags: javascript

So when I execute the following code it gets the value. Though the program goes through and clicks some stuff for me and the value naturally changes. But I wish to save the value of this beforehand and then compare it to the second value.

Executed code :

```
var Category = [];

var ID1;
var ID2;

var dispatchMouseEvent = function(target, var_args) {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    target.dispatchEvent(e);
}

var Level1Cats = document.getElementsByClassName("p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry "); //GETTING LEVEL 1 CATS

var Level1CatsLen = Level1Cats.length; //GETTING LEVEL 1 CAT LEN

for (i = 0; i <= Level1CatsLen-1; i++) {

    var ID1 = Level1Cats[i].id;
    var temp1 = Level1Cats[i].innerHTML;
    temp1.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&").replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");

    function GoToLevel2(i) { //GO TO NEXT LEVEL!
    dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "mouseover", true, true);
    dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "click", true, true);
    }

    function GetLevel2() { //GET NEXT LEVEL
    var Level2Cats = document.getElementsByClassName("p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry");
    return Level2Cats.length;
    }

    setTimeout(GoToLevel2(i),100); //RUN IT WITH TIMING
    var Level2CatsLen = GetLevel2();

    // END OF LEVEL 1
    var extracats2 = Level2CatsLen - Level1CatsLen;
    console.log(extracats2+"e");
    if (extracats2 !== 2 || extracats2 !== 0) {
        for (ii = 0; ii < extracats2; ii++) { //LEVEL 2
        console.log(ii);
        ID2 = Level2Cats[ii+Level1CatsLen].id;
        var temp2 = Level2Cats[ii+Level1CatsLen].innerHTML;
        temp2.replace(/&amp;/, "&").replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");

var Level2Children = []; 
for (l = 0; l < level1CatsLen; l++) {
    Level2Children.push(Level2Cats[l].id);
} 

//DO SOMETHING WITH CATEGORIES - Level 1

Category.push({Name: temp1, ID: ID2, ParentID: 'null', ChildrenIDs: Level2Children});

//FINISH
```

Though when it finishes, if I call Level1CatsLen it is not 16, which is the inital number it is now 33 which is the final stage.

Any ideas how one would go about doing this?

Comment: This value must survive page refresh or not?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here..

Comment: U meant element with class name "p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry" will change and its state need to be stored ?

Comment: you can maintain that value in cookie or you can use local storage for it

Comment: You need to be more specific. Right now what you are saying makes sense to you , not us. Please provide more details and possibly more code...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**:

There are a couple of issues here.

1. You have function declarations within control structures, which is a syntax error:

   ```
   // ...
   for (i = 0; i <= Level1CatsLen-1; i++) {

       var ID1 = Level1Cats[i].id;
       var temp1 = Level1Cats[i].innerHTML;
       temp1.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&").replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");

       function GoToLevel2(i) {                       // <=== Error
       dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "mouseover", true, true);
       dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "click", true, true);
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Browsers have a tendency to tolerate it, but the *way* they tolerate it varies from browser to browser. To create a function within a control structure, you need to use a function *expression*, not a function declaration:

   ```
   var GoToLevel2 = function(i) {
   dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "mouseover", true, true);
   dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "click", true, true);
   };
   ```

   But see #2.
2. There's no need to recreate your functions on every loop, if you're going to pass `i` into them anyway.
3. Your `setTimeout` call is incorrect:

   ```
   setTimeout(GoToLevel2(i),100);
   ```

   That *calls* `GoToLevel2`, passing in `i`, and passes its *return value* into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

   To set up a timed callback to `GoToLevel2`, you use the function reference. To ensure that it receives a specific value (`i`), you can use `Function#bind` to get a new function that will call `GoToLevel2` with that `i`:

   ```
   setTimeout(GoToLevel2.bind(null, i),100);
   ```

It's possible there are further issues, those are the ones that jumped out at me.

---

**Original answer**:

You're doing that, on this line:

```
var Level1CatsLen = Level1Cats.length;
```

As the DOM changes, `Level1Cats.length` may change (because `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `NodeList`), but `Level1CatsLen` won't.

```js
var Level1Cats = document.getElementsByClassName("p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry");
var Level1CatsLen = Level1Cats.length;
snippet.log("Initial: Level1CatsLen = " + Level1CatsLen + ", Level1Cats.length = " + Level1Cats.length);
tick();

function tick() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry";
  div.innerHTML = String(Level1Cats.length + 1);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  snippet.log("Updated: Level1CatsLen = " + Level1CatsLen + ", Level1Cats.length = " + Level1Cats.length);
  if (Level1Cats.length < 10) {
    setTimeout(tick, 500);
  }
}
```

```css
.p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry">1</div>
<div class="p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry">2</div>
<div class="p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry">3</div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay so I believe I may have been clear. This page has javascript categories that are populated dynamically. Sorry if these terms aren't the correct use..
So I originally grab the length for Level1Cats but it seems to change by the end of the for loops, even though this is outside. It is almost like it is grabbed at the time Level1CatsLen is called.

Comment: @MattBiggs: I've updated the answer to address the code you added.